# Big-O/Big-Oh Notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am attempting to calculate the Big-O of the following algorithm but I am confused and require some assistance:

```
Algorithm 1. DFS(G,n)
Input: G- the graph
       n- the current node
1) Visit(n)
2) Mark(n)
3) For every edge nm (from n to m) in G do
4)     If m is not marked then
5)         Dfs(G,m)
6)     End If
7) End For
Output: Depends on the purpose of the search...
```

I won't even begin to say what I (incorrectly) calculated the solution to be.  Can anybody please help me and explain this to me?

Thank you.

EDIT:  Apparently my calculation of `O(n+m)` is correct...can somebody verify this?

EDIT 2:  Or is it `O(|n|+|m|)`?

Comment: Noo, you really should say what you calculated it to be considering this is homework and no one will help if you don't prove you at the very least tried.

Comment: I think you should begin by going through your reasoning and we'll help you out.  Don't be embarrassed by it, it's better to show that you've tried, otherwise we'll just assume you're getting us to do your homework for you :-).

Comment: @Justin I would just like to point out that this is in fact revision and not homework.  Therefore, I am the one who has decided to try and calculate the Big-O of this algorithm through my own choice.  If you absolutely must know, however, then I calculated it to be O(n+m).  As you can see, this is (almost certainly) incorrect as I have not seen any Big-O to result in O(x+y)...

@Mark I hope that this validates my reasoning! :-D

Comment: @Mick What you have is correct, in fact, it is explained in quite a bit of detail on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_first_search.

Comment: @Darhuuk No way...I have amazed myself!  From the Wikipedia page, it appears to be O(|x| + |y|) (the cardinality of x plus the cardinality of y).  Is this correct...?

Comment: @Mick Yes, seems fairly straightforward: you visit every node once and to do that, you must traverse every edge at least once, so O(|n| + |e|).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its cost is O(n + e ) where n is the number of nodes and e the number of edges.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple DFS on a graph, try doing some simple examples of the algorithm, and figure out how many iterations you have to do, and see how that relates to your input values (n number of nodes, and m number of edges)

Answer (score 0):

Lets integrate across all nodes in G

- line 1 and line 2 gets called once for each node in G; i.e. O(N) where N is the number of nodes
- lines 4 gets called once for each edge in G; i.e. O(E) where E is the number of edges.
- line 5 gets called once for each node in G (except for the node we started with); i.e. O(N).

That makes the computation `O(N + E)` which can be reduced to `O(E)` since `E >= N`.

This assumes that we are just counting the steps as equal.  In practice we don't know the relative cost of the different steps.  When those are plugged in, the complexity might be different.